# Best way to create book publication back end

Tags: asp.net

i want to create automated web based book publication system.
My company is publishing reports which is written in words. & there is lots of hassel on formatting word document. 
So we want to develop system where different users can loged into system then create different chapters & different parts within that chapters.
Can anyone suggest any opensource project or any guidelines to achieve the things mentioned above.

Comment: Interesting question, but also very broad.

Comment: How about the way Wikipedia works? Or, in fact, any wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of wiki seems like the way to go in my opinion, you could set it up so users could only edit their own stuff pretty easily. There are some example ASP.NET wikis and other examples that might interest you on [this page](http://www.asp.net/community/projects).